# Can a DOORS real-number attribute be assigned a nonfinite value?

Tags: ibm-doors

I've got a DOORS module with attributes that are filled with number strings, because the attributes are not applicable to all objects. To identify unambiuously the objects which aren't affected, the attributes currently contain "N/A" .  For purposes of sorting and other operations, I would like to replace these attributes with numeric types.  Is there any special value that DOORS understands as "NULL" or "N/A", or even 'Inf' that can be used in a numeric attribute?

I know I could do some scripting to create separate DXL attributes which convert the number strings to numeric but would rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that you will either have to stick to strings or define your personal integer value which represents 'n/a', for example '0'. Objects with the '0' value will be easy to treat after sorting -- with DXL you may use the `bool null(t value)` function which checks if `value` is null (bool: false, char: '0', int: 0, real: 0.0, string: ""). If you stick to integer strings, there is the function `bool isValidInt(string s)` which would help you to treat the "n/a" string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just leave the attribute empty for that object?

It seems like an int type attribute can be set to "" - and you could filter the objects based on that attribute being empty or non-empty.

Interestingly, in DXL space, the following seems to work for an integer based attribute ( inttest )

```
Object o = current
int x = o."inttest"
print ( x ) "\n"
print ( null x ) "\n"
print ( x == 0 )
```

Prints the following results:

```
0
true
true
```

So nulls are interpreted into 0 - something to be aware of if 0 is an expected value in your attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use zero, or blank.  The attribute is incomplete and we need to be certain of the difference between "not filled in yet"  and "not applicable for this use case"  .  And yes, zero is a valid value for many line items.

Comment: If that's the case, I think Twonky's answer above is probably best. You might also wish to add a dxl trigger to the attribute pre-save that checks if the string is a valid int or equal to "N/A".